# why does a stack program segment have executable attribute

Tags: linux, elf

Here is a dump from a.out

`STACK off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**2`
`filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rwx`

Why does a stack segment have executable attribute?

Why isn't there a heap segment with rw- attribute?

//On ubuntu 32bit machine. Program is a simple hello world.

Command:
`ld test.o startup.s; objdump -dhSxt -M intel-pneumonic a.out` 
//startup.s has a small assembly code with _start symbol which calls main and exits after main returns.

Comment: You'll need to give your compiler flags and the command you're running.

Comment: @teppic nothing special. just gcc test.c; Added that to Q.

Comment: The stack is allowed to be executable, but I'm surprised it's a default. On my copy of Ubuntu it isn't.

Comment: @teppic, I apologize. the actual command I used was ld test.o startup.s, where I had assembly code with _startup symbol. There is some context here - http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Command: gcc test.c

Try `gcc test.c -Wl,-z,noexecstack`.

That should be the default on any reasonably modern distribution.